# Controller not being properly activated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have added a controller to my project named UserManager (automatically generated from the ado.net framework)

When I start the application, attempts to navigate to http://server/UserManager/  are met with a 404 error, but if I go to http://server/UserManager/Index the action is found and executes properly.

Is this a case of the controller not being called or is it just not treating index as the default action.  Where are these properties set?

**UPDATE**

It seems that the problem derived from the fact that the default route is set to

```
"Default", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Permits", action = "ListApplications", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

This conflicts with the naming scheme for Usermanager (where the default is Index)

I struggled with ohow to add alternate routes that provided for default actions, but eventually figured out that the order of route addition determines which route takes the request (the earlier the route is added, the more chances it has to meet the criteria.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the default route mapping specifies "Index" as the default action in your global.asax file.

Check that you have the following setting in your global.asax file:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

IN REPLY TO YOUR COMMENT:

Only by way of adding new route mappings. You also need to be aware that the first matching route mapping will be applied, so the order you specify the mappings in Global.asax is crucial.
For example, we wanted our FAQ controller to work with a URL http://domain/faq/{id} without the action specified in the URL, so we declared the following mapping before the default:

```
routes.MapRoute("Faq", "Faq/{id}", new { controller = "Faq", action = "Answer" });
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, is there a way I can specify different default actions for different controllers?

Answer (score 1):

In Global.asax.cs, check the default route is set up:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {
        controller = "Home", 
        action  = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Also, check that the controller is called `UserManagerController`, and derives from `Controller`